# Why am I getting long docker build times in Azure pipeline?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, docker-build

I'm having issues on troubleshooting long build times for my ADO pipeline. Build steps are taking much longer than expected. We're using self-hosted agents - I suspect there may be a problem there, but I wanted input on any other directions I should take in investigating.

Comment: Hi smomma , could you share the latest status of your issue? has my answer helped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, do you mean that same pipeline run via microsoft hosted agent takes much shorter time?

It's suggested that you could check the pipeline debug logs from microsoft-hosted agent and self-hosted agent to see which part of the task and which step would perform different speed. And you could also share the logs with us for investigations.

And you could configure another self hosted agent on another local machine to test again. Usually, the time spent on same pipeline run through different agent would vary from agent performance

And for more information, pipeline run on self-hosted agent would be effected by multiple factors, like hardware property, network transmission and other concept.

Comment: The issue turned out to be that the kubernetes nodes that the runner pods were hosted on were underprovisioned. Ceenos suggestion of running it on a different machine (set up a different node that only runs runner pods) cleared up the issue. Ty